# Why didn't Kamesenin just chose to destroy the saiyan space ship when Vegeta and Nappa was on their way to earth?

Tags: dragon-ball-z

During [**Vegeta Saga**](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Vegeta_Saga)

As I know, Bulma has asked Shenlong to kill the saiyans before they reached Earth. But, Shenlong said that the he couldn't do that because the Saiyans are stronger than him.

I am just wondering.. Since saiyans couldn't live in outer space. Why wouldn't they wish for destroying their space ships instead of resurrecting Goku? What's your opinion about this?

Comment: Since Saiyans have quite advanced technology,  we can assume that it has great defenses. Shenlong can not make something that would be impossible to God, so we can guess that it was impossible for them

Comment: @Ikaros But but, shenlong can resurrect earth, moreover he can even remove bombs inside android#17..

Comment: @choz but weren't those from Dende's dragon rather than Kami/Picccolo's which could only grant 1 wish while Dende's can grant 2. arguably that would make Dende's more powerful and remember a Dragon can't do anything beyond the power of it's creator

Comment: We do not know the resistance of those ships so it is only a guess

Comment: Fair enough, yeah I forgot that they're Dende's dragon @Memor-X

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR : God is not strong enough to destroy those ships, therefore Shenron isn't either.**

For the same reason why Shenlong can not kill the Saiyans, he may not be able to destroy the ships.

[On the Dragon Ball Wiki](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Dragon_Ball_%28object%29#History) :

> Shenron can grant a wish within its powers as long as it does not kill, create love, repeat a wish he previously granted, **surpasses its creator's power**, and a few more restrictions.

We do not know the resistance of those ships, but we know two things

- It was built with really higher technology than the one present on earth
- It is strong enough  to resist a fall and crash from space

Considering those, we can assume that God, which is as strong as Piccolo at this moment of the manga, is not strong enough to destroy it

Comment: I'd rather believe this. Otherwise, Bulma and Roshi were just an idiot

Comment: Though Gohan could shatter it when he powered up as a toddler, which he did right before he attacked radditz

Comment: @Ryan At this moment of the manga, Gohan is stronger than Piccolo so it does make sense

Comment: @Ikaros while that is true, Only gohan tried to destroy it, and did so with ease, and kept on powering up. Piccolo could charge his Special beam cannon to about the same power level